# How to use pyspark to efficiently keep only those groupbs from dataframe that satisfy a certain group specific filter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let us use the following dummy data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,3),(1,40),(1,0),(2,3),(2,1),(2,4),(3,2),(3,4)],['a','b'])
df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1| 40|
|  1|  0|
|  2|  3|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  4|
|  3|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

1. How to filter out the data groups that do not have average(b) > 6

Expected output:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1| 40|
|  1|  0|
+---+---+
```

How I am achieving it:

```
df_filter = df.groupby('a').agg(F.mean(F.col('b')).alias("avg"))

df_filter = df_filter.filter(F.col('avg') > 6.)

df.join(df_filter,'a','inner').drop('avg').show()
```

Problem:

1. The shuffle happens twice. Once for computing the df_filter and the other time for the join.

```
df_filter = df.groupby('a').agg(F.mean(F.col('b')).alias("avg"))

df_filter = df_filter.filter(F.col('avg') > 6.)

df.join(df_filter,'a','inner').drop('avg').explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Project [a#175L, b#176L]
+- *(5) SortMergeJoin [a#175L], [a#222L], Inner
   :- *(2) Sort [a#175L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#175L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=919]
   :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(a#175L)
   :        +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[a#175L,b#176L]
   +- *(4) Sort [a#222L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- *(4) Project [a#222L]
         +- *(4) Filter (isnotnull(avg#219) AND (avg#219 > 6.0))
            +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[a#222L], functions=[avg(b#223L)])
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#222L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=925]
                  +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[a#222L], functions=[partial_avg(b#223L)])
                     +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(a#222L)
                        +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[a#222L,b#223L]
```

If I think about it I should just shuffle the data once on the key `a` and then no more shuffles are needed since every partition would be self sufficient.

Question: In general, What is the efficient way to exclude the data groups that do not satisfy a group-dependent filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Window` functionality instead of doing groupBy + join,

```
out = df.withColumn("avg", avg(col("b")).over(Window.partitionBy("a")))\
    .where("avg>6").drop("avg")

out.explain()
out.show()

+- Project [a#0L, b#1L]
   +- Filter (isnotnull(avg#5) AND (avg#5 > 6.0))
      +- Window [avg(b#1L) windowspecdefinition(a#0L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS avg#5], [a#0L]
         +- Sort [a#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#0L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=16]
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]


+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1| 40|
|  1|  0|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) ! With pandas background, the window functionality didn't occur to me